# Can a vagrant provisioner respond to changes made on the guest before it's run?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm using vagrant and ansible to create and provision an environment.  I've gotten everything to work fine, but I found that there were a couple commands which took a long time to execute. Since ansible doesn't provide a way to see live output of a shell command, I decided to separate those commands out to separate shell scripts and execute them as shell provisioners in order to see their output.  This worked when I experimented with the process by putting the shell provisioner at the *end* of the Vagrantfile (after the Ansible provisioner), but it's causing problems if I break up the process.  Here's a high-level, pseudo example:

I have 3 playbooks: setup.yml, post-download.yml, and post-sample-data.yml

The desired flow goes like this:

```
    Vagrantfile
      provisioner: "ansible", playbook "setup.yml"
        - Tasks...
        - Create shell scripts for upcoming shell provisioners...
        - meta: end_play

      provisioner: "shell", inline: "bin/bash /path/to/created/shell/script"
        (run script)

      provisioner: "ansible", playbook "post-download.yml"
         - Tasks...
         - meta: end_play

      provisioner: "shell", inline: "bin/bash /path/to/created/shell/script"
        (run script)

      provisioner: "ansible", playbook "post-sample-data.yml"
        - Tasks...
        - meta: end_play

      provisioner: "shell", inline: "bin/bash /path/to/created/shell/script"
        (run script)

    end
```

When I run `vagrant provision` with this idea in mind, I get the following error on the first shell provisioner attempt:

`/tmp/vagrant-shell: line 1: bin/sh: No such file or directory`

Based on the error message, my assumption is that the vagrant shell is unable to react to changes made on the server during the Vagrantfile execution; ergo, it can't find the created shell scripts to run as provisioners after the initial ansible provisioner runs.  Is that what's happening, or is there a way I can make this approach work?

In case it helps, here's the actual code from my vagrantfile:

```
# Kick off the pre-install Ansible provisioner
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "ansible/setup.yml"
end

# Kick off the installation, and sample data shell scripts so we can get terminal output
if settings['project']['install_method'] == 'install' || settings['project']['install_method'] == 'reinstall'
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/download.sh" 
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "ansible/post-download.yml"
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/install.sh"
end

# Kick off the sample data shell script to download the sample data packages so we can get terminal output
if settings['use_sample_data'] == true
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/sample-data.sh" 
end

# Kick off the post-sample-data Ansible provisioner
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "ansible/post-sample-data.yml"
end

# Kick off the cache warmer script so we can get terminal output
if settings['project']['warm_cache'] == true
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/cache-warmer.sh"
end
```

Comment: It should be `/bin/sh or /bin/bash` and not bin/sh or bin/bash

Comment: Wow - what a stupid mistake on my part.  Thanks for this, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @tux above, I can confirm that this approach will work for showing output between playbooks so long as the ansible project is well-structured, etc.

For those curious, here's the updated version of the Vagrantfile:

```
# Kick off the pre-install Ansible provisioner
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "ansible/setup.yml"
end

# Kick off the installation, and sample data shell scripts so we can get terminal output
if settings['project']['install_method'] == 'install' || settings['project']['install_method'] == 'reinstall'
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: "/bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/download.sh" 
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "ansible/post-download.yml"
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: "/bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/install.sh"
end

# Kick off the sample data shell script to download the sample data packages so we can get terminal output
if settings['use_sample_data'] == true
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: "/bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/sample-data.sh" 
end

# Kick off the post-sample-data Ansible provisioner
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "ansible/post-sample-data.yml"
end

# Kick off the cache warmer script so we can get terminal output
if settings['project']['warm_cache'] == true
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "/bin/sh #{settings['installation']['directory']}/cache-warmer.sh"
end
```

Note the use of `privileged: false` in all but the last script provisioner.  This is necessary if you **don't** want the script to be executed as the root user.